# get list view with specific records from server based on email address sent from android

Tags: java, php, android, email

**I have a table in the server and I want to retrieve specific records based on email address sent from android java code.**

**The email address is stored in global variable and I can get its value but I don't know how to send its value to the server and get the records.**

**my code retrieves all the records from the table**

**Please Help me to do it, I tried to do it for 3 days but with no solution**

**this is my PHP code :**

```
<?php
$objConnect = mysql_connect("****","******","******");
$objDB = mysql_select_db("******");
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM Appointment ";
$objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL);
$intNumField = mysql_num_fields($objQuery);
$resultArray = array();
while($obResult = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery))
{
    $arrCol = array();
    for($i=0;$i<$intNumField;$i++)
    {
        $arrCol[mysql_field_name($objQuery,$i)] = $obResult[$i];
    }
    array_push($resultArray,$arrCol);
}

mysql_close($objConnect);

echo json_encode($resultArray);
?>
```

**this is my java code :**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.StatusLine;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.ClipData;
import android.content.ClipboardManager;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ServicesBMWGarageActivity extends Activity {

private ClipData myClip;

private ClipboardManager myClipboard;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.services_bmw_garage);

    GlobalClass globalVariable = (GlobalClass) getApplicationContext();
    // Get email from global/application context
    final String Email  = globalVariable.getEmail();

    myClipboard = (ClipboardManager)getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);

    // Permission StrictMode
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }

    // listView1
    final ListView lisView1 = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);   


    String url = "http://ec2-54-148-64-28.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/Codiad/workspace/BMWdatabase/MyAppointments.php";

    try {

        JSONArray data = new JSONArray(getJSONUrl(url));

        final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> MyArrList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        HashMap<String, String> map;

        for(int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++){
            JSONObject c = data.getJSONObject(i);

            map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put("A_ID", c.getString("A_ID"));
            map.put("A_Model", c.getString("A_Model"));
            map.put("A_Services", c.getString("A_Services"));
            map.put("A_DATE", c.getString("A_DATE"));
            MyArrList.add(map);

        }


        SimpleAdapter sAdap;
        sAdap = new SimpleAdapter(ServicesBMWGarageActivity.this, MyArrList, R.layout.activity_column,
                new String[] {"A_ID", "A_Model", "A_Services", "A_DATE"}, new int[] {R.id.ColMemberID, R.id.ColName, R.id.ColTel,R.id.Coldate });      
        lisView1.setAdapter(sAdap);

        final AlertDialog.Builder viewDetail = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        // OnClick Item
        lisView1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> myAdapter, View myView,
                    int position, long mylng) {

                String A_ID1 = MyArrList.get(position).get("A_ID")
                        .toString();
                String Type1 = MyArrList.get(position).get("A_Model")
                        .toString();
                String Model1 = MyArrList.get(position).get("A_Services")
                        .toString();
                String Model2 = MyArrList.get(position).get("A_DATE")
                        .toString();
                final String phoneNumber = MyArrList.get(position).get("A_ID")
                        .toString();
                //String sMemberID = ((TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.ColMemberID)).getText().toString();
                // String sName = ((TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.ColName)).getText().toString();
                // String sTel = ((TextView) myView.findViewById(R.id.ColTel)).getText().toString();

                viewDetail.setIcon(android.R.drawable.btn_star_big_on);
                viewDetail.setTitle("Appointment Detail");
                viewDetail.setMessage("ID : " + A_ID1 + "\n"
                        + "Vehicle Model : " + Type1 + "\n" + "Service Type : " + Model1
                        + "\n" + "Date : " + Model2);
                viewDetail.setPositiveButton("OK",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                String text = phoneNumber;
                                myClip = ClipData.newPlainText("text", text);
                                myClipboard.setPrimaryClip(myClip);
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Appointment ID Copied", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                viewDetail.show();

            }
        });


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}


public String getJSONUrl(String url) {
    StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
    try {
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
        if (statusCode == 200) { // Download OK
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream content = entity.getContent();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                str.append(line);
            }
        } else {
            Log.e("Log", "Failed to download results..");
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return str.toString();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_activity_home_page, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

Comment: There is nothing in your php script that resembles an email variable. So it makes no sense to send an email address. You first have to decide how the script wants to receive an email address. If you have done that you can implement the right code to send it. But to start you have a `NetworkOnMainThreadException`. Look at the LogCat and you will see. You have to place the http code in an AsyncTask or Thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer and the problem is solved

It was an easy solution

I just put my condition in the java code with no changes in the PHP code

the changes are :

```
try {
        JSONArray data = new JSONArray(getJSONUrl(url));

        final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> MyArrList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,    String>>();
        HashMap<String, String> map;

        for(int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++){
            JSONObject c = data.getJSONObject(i);
            map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put("V_ID", c.getString("V_ID"));
            map.put("V_Type", c.getString("V_Type"));
            map.put("V_Model", c.getString("V_Model"));
            map.put("V_Year", c.getString("V_Year"));
            map.put("V_Plate", c.getString("V_Plate"));
            map.put("ImagePath", c.getString("ImagePath"));
            map.put("Email", c.getString("Email"));

            String email = c.getString("Email");
              GlobalClass globalVariable = (GlobalClass) getApplicationContext();
              // Get name and email from global/application context
              final String Email  = globalVariable.getEmail();

             if(email.equals(Email))
            MyArrList.add(map);
        }
```